# Extracting different coloured arrows with noise

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection, ui-automation

Given an image like this, how would I go about extracting only the arrows? I'm having trouble filtering all the noise, and it's difficult to filter the colour since the arrows can either be in the HSV range of blue and red. My goal is to have just the 4 arrows showing in the image and nothing else.

Here are some of the different photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I've tried so far with OpenCV-Python:

- Applying GaussianBlur
- Grabbing hue and then applying canny
- Drawing contours
- Filtering by colour, then applying canny (difficult because arrows can be different colours)

In the end, none of these did a good job in filtering for the arrows.

Comment: Convert to LAB. Then take the maximum between the A and B channels pixel by pixel. Now try thresholding and then get contours.

Comment: Hey thanks @fmw42, this worked much better! However, I'm still running into issues like this. Seems like the arrow is not being fully contoured.

https://imgur.com/a/TUSZGOe

Ideally, it would look like this:
https://imgur.com/a/3uWRitH

Do you have any ideas on how I could achieve this result?

Comment: please show a video. I suspect that these things are "scrolling" their gradient. also please show a good sampling of the appearance variation of these things. your image makes it look like they only show in four directions but do they really? -- why don't you just hook into the game process and extract the data directly? -- why not just train an AI to detect these objects? an AI can learn that the color gradient is always aligned with the direction of an arrow, among other things

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, thanks for the comment! For this problem, they do only show four arrows, although there is also a problem later on where the arrows spin and shutter at the direction it should be facing. The game is able to detect if you hook into it, and I'm not too sure about the process of training AI. I am using another model that is able to decipher it if the image is well preprocessed though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach in Python/OpenCV that works for the image provided. I am not sure if it works for all the image. Perhaps the threshold needs adjusting for each.

- Read the input
- Convert to LAB colorspace
- Separate LAB channels
- Get pixel-by-pixel maximum between the A and B channels
- Threshold
- Apply morphology close
- Get contours
- Filter the contours on area and perimeter
- Draw the remaining contours as white filled on a black background
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('game_arrows.png')

# convert to LAB
LAB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# separate channels
L,A,B = cv2.split(LAB)

# get the maximum between the A and B pixel by pixel
ABmax = np.maximum(A, B)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(ABmax, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# morphology close and open
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# filter contours
result = np.zeros_like(img)
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cntr, True)
    if area > 300 and perimeter < 200:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('game_arrows_ABmax.jpg', ABmax)
cv2.imwrite('game_arrows_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('game_arrows_morph.jpg', morph)
cv2.imwrite('game_arrows_result.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('ABmax', ABmax)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Maximum of A and B channels:

[image]

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology Closed Image:

[image]

Filtered Contours:

[image]

Comment: is it alright if I asked you some follow up questions?

Comment: Yes, go ahead and ask. Note I do not think this will work for all of your images above, esp the first one. But I have not explored that.

Comment: Just two follow ups:
1) From this, what would be a fast way to find the directions of the arrows? Currently I am running a tensorflow model on the individual arrows, but this can be quite slow. If there's anything I should keep my eye out for for this, that would be great!
2) Out of curiosity, there is another problem attached to this. In the photo that you sent, the arrow is moving and it shakes when it is facing the correct direction of the arrow. This is an example of a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1C7L2VkMUaA
Just curious of your thoughts on how to tackle this problem! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I know that's a lot haha! Thanks a ton either way.

Comment: 1) I do not have any great ideas. Perhaps getting the medial axis might help.  2) If you can solve 1), then I do not see why 2) is an issue. Each frame will have a slightly different angle. You can track the angles and see when it is shaking back and forth near some angle.

Comment: 1) Search Google on "python opencv get angle of arrow". It seems to return several links that might answer your problem

Comment: For 2) The problem is that I can't seem to be able to know when to stop. Would I take multiple photos and then find that case when the angles start to increase/decrease?

Comment: I don't understand. Did you not say your had a video and can then process every frame?

Comment: What I do is when these arrows show up, I take a picture and then process that picture. Would taking multiple photos be able to achieve this effect?

Comment: Achieve what effect?  If it works for one image of a game it should work for any number of images of the game provided that the background is about the same.